# Html table in CISCO Webex Teams

Tags: cisco, webex

Has anyone tried printing/sharing a html table in Cisco Webex (with markdown or anything)?

I have been trying, but never works.
Not formatted correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I've been able to do is use Markdown table syntax.  Unfortunately
Use a markdown table generator such as [here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and make sure you right click and paste as snippet (Ctrl+Shift+V on Windows).  You can also paste within the markdown code block.
Webex will not show it as a table, but will make it look like a table using dashes and vertical bars.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear: Webex does not (as of yet) support tables in messages.  As both previous answers hint at you can at best *simulate* a tabular syntax by using code block format (```) and fixed-width or | delimited "columns", so best suited for cells with short content

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap your code with (get rid of the '' when you wrap, just the back tick)

'``` html (optional)'

'```'

This should work.